# GraphQL schema error

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

So when I start my server I get this list of errors

`/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:966
  throw (0, _error.syntaxError)(lexer.source, token.start, 'Expected ' + kind + ', found ' + (0, _lexer.getTokenDesc)(token));
  ^
GraphQLError
    at syntaxError (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:28:15)
    at expect (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:966:32)
    at parseName (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:88:15)
    at parseInputValueDef (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:743:14)
    at many (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1015:16)
    at parseArgumentDefs (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:735:10)
    at parseFieldDefinition (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:714:14)
    at any (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1002:16)
    at parseObjectTypeDefinition (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:683:16)
    at parseTypeSystemDefinition (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:607:16)
    at parseDefinition (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:148:16)
    at parseDocument (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:106:22)
    at Object.parse (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:43:10)
    at buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/schemaGenerator.ts:145:37)
    at _generateSchema (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/schemaGenerator.ts:72:18)
    at makeExecutableSchema (/Users/charlie/workspace/HackQLServer/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/schemaGenerator.ts:97:20)`

With all of this showing up. I don't really understand where my error is. Here is my schema file where I assume the error is

```
const typeDefinitions = `
    type Author {
      id: Int
      firstName: String
      lastName: String
      posts: [Post]
    }

    type Post {
      id: Int
      title: String
      text: String
      author: Author
    }

type Query {
  author(firstName: String, lastName: String): Author
  allPosts(): [Post!]!
}

schema {
  query: Query
}`

export default [typeDefinitions]
```

Also here is my resolvers file if you think the errors could be stemming from it

```
import { Author, Post } from './connectors'

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    author: (root, args) => {
      return Author.find({ where: args })
    },
    allPosts: (root, args) => {
      return Post.findAll()
    },
    allAuthors: (root, args) => {
      return Author.findAll()
    }
  },
  Author: {
    posts: (author) => {
      return author.getPosts()
    }
  },
  Post: {
    author: (post) => {
      return post.getAuthor()
    }
  }
}

export default resolvers
```

If you see anything please let me know because I can't figure this one out. I am also using Sequelize for my DB connection with sqlite in case you are wondering what the syntax may be for my model queries.

Answer (score 6):

I think the error is in this line

`type Query {
  author(firstName: String, lastName: String): Author
  allPosts(): [Post!]!
}`

since `allPost` has no parameters, it the parentesis aren't needed. it should be

`type Query {
  author(firstName: String, lastName: String): Author
  allPosts: [Post!]!
}`

running into cryptic errors like this,
`throw (0, _error.syntaxError)(lexer.source, token.start, 'Expected ' + kind + ', found ' + (0, _lexer.getTokenDesc)(token))` is most likely caused by invalid syntax in the schema file